# Creating columns with string format in C# WPF

Tags: c#, string, format

I want to dynamically create table just by strings in ListBox. 
All columns should be even. Unfortunately I am still getting something like this:
1-- 25----123
10---25----123

Instead of this:
1---- 25----123
10---25----123

I'm using string.Format() method to achive it. My data comes as file. Rows are splited with '\n', values with ' '. Code looks like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<amountOfVariables; i++) tableFormat += "{" + i + ",-20" + "}";
object[] values = line.Split(' ');
if(values.Length==amountOfVariables) main.data_list1.Items.Add(string.Format(tableFormat, values));
```

Sample data:
line: "1 123 1234"
values: {"1","123","1234"}
tableFormat: "{0,-20}{1,-20}{2,-20}"
File contains a lot of lines.

I dont know why it doesnt work, maybe there is another solution?

Comment: You should describe the actual outcome vs. your expected outcome, rather than just "it doesn't work"

Comment: Also, what is `line`? It would be very helpful if you could post sample code that people can copy paste, like: `var values = new object[] {"one", "two", "three"};`

Comment: Use a UI element (some control derived from ItemsControl) that allows you to present your data in a table/grid-like fashion (like [ListBox with a GridView](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/), for example). No need to painfully hack something with string.Format in trying to make something look "nice" in the WPF UI...